# asp.net mvc3 return another view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

here is the problem

```
 public ActionResult One()
 {
   if(condition)
     return View()
   else
     return Two()
 }

 public ActionResult Two()
 {
   return View()
 }
```

how can I do that without error

Comment: What error? I suggest explicitly saying the views name, like View("name")

Answer (score 3):

Change your code to:

```
public ActionResult One()
 {
   if(condition)
     return View();
   else
     RedirectToAction("Two");
 }

 public ActionResult Two()
 {
   return View();
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Just return the view by name (`return view("nameOfView")`), or use `RedirectToAction` or `RedirectToRoute`

Answer (score 2):

Simply use:

```
 public ActionResult One()
 {
   if(condition)
     return View()
   else
     return View("Two")
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

oh I've solved the problem

```
 public ActionResult Two()
 {
   return View("Two")
 }
```